# WebClient - dealing with XSRF/CSRF tokens

Tags: spring, spring-webclient

I'm trying to connect to API with CSRF protection using WebClient. How `ExchangeFilterFunction` could look like to handle `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie and include `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header?

Answer (score 0):

That's the solution I came up with:

```
public class CsrfClientExchangeFilterFunction implements ExchangeFilterFunction
{
    @Override
    public Mono<ClientResponse> filter( ClientRequest request, ExchangeFunction next)   {
        return next.exchange( request )
            .flatMap( response -> {
                if( response.statusCode().is4xxClientError() )
                {
                    ResponseCookie csrfCookie = response.cookies().getFirst( "XSRF-TOKEN" );
                    if( csrfCookie != null )
                    {
                        ClientRequest retryRequest = ClientRequest.from( request )
                                .headers( httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.set( "X-XSRF-TOKEN", csrfCookie.getValue() ) )
                                .cookies( cookies -> cookies.add(  "XSRF-TOKEN", csrfCookie.getValue() ) )
                                .build();

                        return next.exchange( retryRequest );
                    }
                }
                return Mono.just( response );
            } );
    }
}
```

For reference, it doesn't work if `ClientRequest.Builder#cookie(String name, String... values)` is used instead of `ClientRequest.Builder#cookies(Consumer<MultiValueMap<String, String>> cookiesConsumer)`. I would love to know why though!

**Edit:**

Different behaviour of `ClientRequest.Builder#cookies` and `ClientRequest.Builder#cookie` methods has been reported as an issue for Spring Framework project - you can find it [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23502)

Comment: Your reported issue is closed as Invalid. You will need to create a sample Spring project for them to debug.